# How to inject mutationobserver to puppeteer

Tags: mutation-observers, puppeteer

I want trace changed DOM like mutationobserver in headless chrome.
So I learning puppeteer library, but don’t know how to use do that.

It’s possible to trace DOM change in puppeteer?? thanks

Comment: It's certainly possible. But not if you don't share what you tried until now and also provide a valid website/test case where you want to trace the dom change.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I got a solve this problem myself.Coding the javascript mutationobserver and inject this code using evaluate puppeteer function.

Comment: Here is a solution: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/2945

Comment: Does this answer your question? [puppeteer wait for page/DOM updates - respond to new items that are added after initial loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54109078/puppeteer-wait-for-page-dom-updates-respond-to-new-items-that-are-added-after)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well,you can inject custom code to the browser.

One way:

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
   const observer = new MutationObserver(
   function() {
     // communicate with node through console.log method
     console.log('__mutation')
    }
   )
   const config = {
     attributes: true,
     childList: true,
     characterData: true,
     subtree: true
   }
   observer.observe(target, config)
})
```

In your node script:

```
page.on('console', async (msg) => {
   if (msg.text === '__mutation') {
     // do something...
   }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, Is that the only hack?
Does Puppeteer have another way doing that?

Comment: @MehdiRaash You could [run `page.waitForFunction` in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69419744/6243352) as an alternative approach. I wouldn't call resorting to `evaluate` a hack, since Puppeteer [doesn't pretend to offer helpers for everything](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/2945#issuecomment-407962655), but you're right that abusing `console.log` as a trigger here is a strange choice. Using [`page.exposeFunction`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54110446/6243352) makes it easier to pass data back to Node from your MutationObserver or trigger a callback than `console.log`.