# Realtime scrape a chat using Nodejs

Tags: node.js, firebase, puppeteer

What I want to do is to build a **scraping** application on NodeJs from which it m*onitors on Realtime a chat and store certain messages within any database?

What I am wanting to do is the following, I am wanting to capture data from the chat platforms streaming, and thus capture some useful information that helps those who are doing the streaming service;

*But I do not know how to start doing this using NodeJs,*

What I have been able to do so far has been to capture the data of the messages, however **I can not monitor** in realtime new messages,
any help in this regard?

What i did so far:

**server.js**

```
var express     = require('express');
var fs          = require('fs');
var request     = require('request');
var puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
var app         = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){

    url = 'https://www.nimo.tv/live/6035521326';

    (async() => {
        
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch();

        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto(url);
        await page.waitForSelector('.msg-nickname');

        const messages = await page.evaluate(() => {
            return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.msg-nickname'))
                    .map(item => item.innerText);
        });

        console.log(messages);
    })();
    res.send('Check your console!')

});

app.listen('8081') 
console.log('Magic happens on port 8081'); 
exports = module.exports = app;
```

With this, I get the Nicknames of Users messages and put in an Array, I want to make my application run and receive new Nicknames automatically when the input is done in the chat,
Any help with this challenge?

Maybe I'm going to need to use WebSocket

Comment: Application chat must go through NodeJS apis then only you can capture it

Comment: If you're automating chrome then you'd probably have to set up event listeners on the DOM where the text of interest is being inserted (and then set up an event based listener from puppeteer to node) or monkeypatch code into their front end library code (and do the same). The best solution would be to drop puppeteer and use their API for listening on either event hooks or an event based socket API that broadcasts the messages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [puppeteer wait for page/DOM updates - respond to new items that are added after initial loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54109078/puppeteer-wait-for-page-dom-updates-respond-to-new-items-that-are-added-after)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If possible you should use the API, the chat is using. Try to open the network tab inside the Chrome developer tools and try to figure out which network requests are happening.

---

If that is not possible, you can use a [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to monitor DOM changes. Expose a function via [`page.exposeFunction`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageexposefunctionname-puppeteerfunction) and then listen to relevant changes. You can then insert the obtained data into a database.

Here is some example code to get you started:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const { Client } = require('pg');

(async () => {
    const client = new Client(/* ... */);
    await client.connect(); // connect to database

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    const [page] = await browser.pages();

    // call a handler when a mutation happens
    async function mutationListener(addedText) {
        console.log(`Added text: ${addedText}`);

        // insert data into database
        await client.query('INSERT INTO users(text) VALUES($1)', [addedText]);
    }
    page.exposeFunction('mutationListener', mutationListener);

    await page.goto('http://...');
    await page.waitForSelector('.msg-nickname');

    await page.evaluate(() => {
        // wait for any mutations inside a specific element (e.g. the chatbox)
        const observerTarget = document.querySelector('ELEMENT-TO-MONITOR');
        const mutationObserver = new MutationObserver((mutationsList) => {
            // handle change by checking which elements were added and which were deleted
            for (const mutation of mutationsList) {
                const { removedNodes, addedNodes } = mutation;
                // example: pass innerText of first added element to our mutationListener
                mutationListener(addedNodes[0].innerText);
            }
        });
        mutationObserver.observe( // start observer
            observerTarget,
            { childList: true }, // wait for new child nodes to be added/removed
        );
    });
})();
```