# Is it possible to trigger an event if a puppeteer browser is on a certain URL or has a certain element on the webpage?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

Is it possible to trigger an event via puppeteer if the browser is on a certain URL or has a certain element on the webpage?

I have a browser open, user interacts with the page and do whatever they want until they are on a certain URL. Is this possible to trigger an event like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Both options you are describing are viable. The easier way would be to check the requests that are happening.

#### Check for requests/URLs

Here is a code sample which checks what requests are happening by listing on the [`request`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.15.0/docs/api.md#event-request) event. Keep in mind that the request could be happening anywhere on the page (in an iframe for example). Depending on your use case, you might therefore also want to check if the request happened inside the main page (by using [`page.url()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.15.0/docs/api.md#pageurl)).

```js
page.on('request', request => {
  const url = request.url();
  if (url === '...') {
     // trigger event
  }
});
```

---

#### Check for an element

If you want to check if a specific element is present on the page, you can wait for the [`domcontentloaded`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.15.0/docs/api.md#event-domcontentloaded) event and then check if the element is present:

```js
page.on('domcontentloaded', () => {
  const element = page.$('#element-selector');
  if (element) {
    // element is present, trigger event
  }
});
```

Keep in mind that, this will only check for it *once*. To continuously check if the element is present, you can use a [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) (see an example for that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55461733/5627599)).