# How to grab data that updates every second using Puppeteer

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I learning Puppeteer and trying to understand how I can grab and save data that is change, as for example, every second.

Here is my code for now:

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer")

const dataUrl = 'https://time.is/';

const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto(dataUrl);

const pageData = await page.evaluate(() => {
    return { html: document.documentElement.innerHTML }
}) 

const $ = cheerio.load(pageData.html)

console.log($('#clock').text())
```

So, by the launch of this script, it will console.log the current time. How I can run await page.evaluate(()... every second to see the time ticker in the terminal from this site? I have an idea to put this

```
const pageData = await page.evaluate(() => {
    return { html: document.documentElement.innerHTML }
})
```

into setTimeout and run every second but not sure how to do it. I googled a lot and do not find how I can get the content of the page every second and return it to cheerio.

Thanks!

Comment: There's no need for Cheerio just to get text. Puppeteer already has selectors, so it's Rube Goldbergian to re-parse the whole page just to access a selector: simply `await page.$eval("#clock", e => e.textContent)` and save a dependency and a lot of extra work. While you can use a loop, RAF, `setTimeout`  or mutationObserver to detect the change, I'm not sure I understand the point of this exercise. You already have a clock built into your computer that tells you the time. Why not read that?

Comment: @ggorlen There are a lot of sites that have a live feed of data in some block, like news in the right block of CNN.com site [link]https://i.imgur.com/A9FN9qT.png[/link]. So I want to know is it possible to get this live feed data and save it somewhere without refreshing the page. time.is is just simplest example

Comment: Can you share the exact site you're scraping and the data you want?

Comment: @ggorlen [link]https://rbc.ru , all news that appears in div with class js-news-feed-list. When a new item appears in the news list I want to save the new item title and some additional info from the page. The issue that news items can appear in time intervals from 1 to 40 minutes and refresh the page every 5-10 seconds is not a solution. So I want to find a method to load the page and then bind a function that will seek for changes in div in a short period of time without refreshing a page and save these changes in mongodb.

Comment: You probably want [puppeteer wait for page/DOM updates - respond to new items that are added after initial loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54109078/puppeteer-wait-for-page-dom-updates-respond-to-new-items-that-are-added-after). Thanks for the details, that makes it much easier to understand what you're trying to achieve.