# Is there an event listener to check if childElements have been added to an elements

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I have a puppeteer project in which I'm waiting for some form of information on an Element. For example, in the header, I'm waiting for some new child Nodes.

```
<div id="outside">
</div>
```

and then after some time

```
<div id="outside">
   <div id='inside'>
   </div>
</div>
```

is there a way for me to add an event listener to check when the HTML has been changed?

something like

```
page.addListener('#outside', () => {
   console.log('event fired');
}
```

Comment: Perhaps this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47903954/how-to-inject-mutationobserver-to-puppeteer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to inject mutationobserver to puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47903954/how-to-inject-mutationobserver-to-puppeteer)

Answer (score 4):

You can try with [**`MutationObserver`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

```js
// Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
const config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true };

// Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
const callback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
  for(let mutation of mutationsList) {
    if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
      console.log('A child node has been added or removed.');
    }
    else if (mutation.type === 'attributes') {
      console.log('The ' + mutation.attributeName + ' attribute was modified.');
    }
  }
};

// Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
const targetNode = document.querySelector('#outside');

// Start observing the target node for configured mutations
observer.observe(targetNode, config);

targetNode.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', "<div id='inside'>Child</div>"); // Add child
targetNode.classList.add('.child'); // Modify attribute
document.querySelector('#inside').style.marginLeft = '15px';
```

```html
<div id="outside">Parent
</div>
```

Comment: What's the difference between childList and subtree?

Comment: @pguardiario, *childList – changes in the direct children of node , subtree – in all descendants of node*. Please visit https://javascript.info/mutation-observer:)