# How do I continuously listen for a new item while scraping a website

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am using puppeteer to scrape a website that is being live updated, to report the latest item elsewhere.
Currently the way I was thinking accomplishing this is to run a setInterval call on my async scrape and to compare if the last item has changed, checking every 30 seconds. I assume there has to be a better way of doing this then that.
Here is my current code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
 playtracker = async () => {
  console.log('loading');
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('URL-Being-Scraped');
  await page.waitForSelector('.playlist-tracklist-view');
  let html = await page.$$eval('.playlist-tracklist-view > .playlist-track', tracks => {
    tracks = tracks.filter(track => track.querySelector('.playlist-trackname').textContent);
    tracks = tracks.map(el => el.querySelector('.playlist-trackname').textContent);
      return tracks;
  });
  console.log('logging', html[html.length-1]);
  };
setInterval(playtracker, 30000)
```

Comment: A bit more info here would be nice. What information are you trying to get and what are the characteristics of the update? This looks like it broadcasts whatever the last track is regardless of whether it's changed or not, so it's unclear how it should know when an update occurred, depending on what the logic is of the site. I assume the receiver is differentiating the change, but that seems like the wrong location to do it. Puppeteer has `waitForFunction` so you can use that to wait for an arbitrary predicate like a changed item, different track count, etc.

Comment: If you don't have control over the website, then no.. there is no standard push mechanism for updates. Unless the website has some kind of websocket system

Comment: @ggorlen I am attempting to scrape live playlists from DJs off of their serato live playlist, the page appends updates every time a new track starts playing, which is why my current plan is to just scrape every 30 seconds, but that got me wondering if there was a way to just have the scraper sort of listen to see if the dom gets appended with the new track

Comment: @ggorlen, the newest track gets added at the bottom of the list, it's easier to show a site then try to explain I suppose, so here is a random djs link, https://serato.com/playlists/eavo/live

Comment: The page seems to periodically send xhr requests to [/loadnewcontents](https://serato.com/parts/forum/threads/loadnewcounts). You could set up listeners for page.on events to find when a request is being sent for this url and response received and extract data from the JSON response.

Answer (score 0):

There is an api called "MutationObserver". You can check that out on MDN. Here's the link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

What it is doing is basically do whatever you want to do when the spesific element has changed. Lets say you have a list you want to listen. What you would do is

```
const listElement = document.querySelector( [list element] );
const callbackFunc = funcion foo () {
  //do something
}

const yourMutationObserver = new MutationObserver(callbackFunc)
yourMutationObserver.observe(listElement)
```

You can disconnect your mutation observer with `yourMutationObserver.disconnect()` method whenever you want.

This could help too if you confused about how to implement it https://stackoverflow.com/a/48145840/14138428